# Significance of AUC score

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-modeling, logistic-regression, machine-learning-model

My model (Logistic Regression) has AUC score of **0.8**

Am I right in stating that the probability of the model ranking a random positive sample higher than a random negative sample is 0.8?
Also, how does this interpretation change if I pick more than 2 random samples *(let's say 5)*? Can I say that the probability of the model to predict highest probability for the best sample *(positive)* out of 5 is 0.8? Or will this become 0.8*0.8*0.8*0.8 = 0.4096?

Comment: what do you mean by "best sample"?

Comment: I meant the one which actually has the highest probability of success (1) out of the 5 samples